# 2019: Can Google Assistant send a message from lock screen?

Tags: sms, lock-screens, 9.0-pie, hands-free

I'm looking for a way to allow Google Assistant's speech-to-text to send a message while phone is locked, preferably only to certain contacts and without being able to read past messages.

I've googled and all solutions seem no longer valid.

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Comment: @helper Not the ideal one, with the ability just to send.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, by using smartlock.

It should be located under security and lock screen.

Click on smart lock then voice match and turn on:
Access with voice match 
And lock screen personal results.

However this may let you read earlier messages and will not restrain it to only selected contacts